# Почему Spring MVC не видит свой конфигурационный файл?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

При попытке запустить приложение на Spring MVC падает `Exception`:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource

Хотя необходимый файл лежит в папке ресурсы. Вот структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это `spring-context.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/view/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.pravvich" />

</beans>
```

Это мой web.xml где я явно указываю где искать этот файл:

```
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Process application servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Хотя при указании `classpath:spring-context.xml` IDE сама посказывает этот файл возможно сам спринг не видит папку ресурсы? Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как это запустить?

Comment: А Вам обязательно нужно чтобы конфиги были в папке ресурсов а не в WEB-INF?  Есть конвенция что конфиги веб приложения лежат именно там.

Comment: @alexandr gaiduchok поправил и располодение конфига, положил в `WEB-INF` и путь в `web.xml` сменил на `WEB-INF/spring-context.xml` но не помогло та же ошибка. Обновил ответ.

Comment: `/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml` забыли `/`

Comment: @alexandr gaiduchok к сожалению не помогло(

Comment: [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException,   я вот у вас не вижу applicationContext.xml, мб переименовать?

Comment: @Jbyh да запустился. Спасибо большое, добавьте ответ что-бы я мог принять.

Comment: Это решение, но обходное. Понять бы почему игнорируется параметр `contextConfigLocation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException, я вот у вас не вижу applicationContext.xml, мб переименовать?

Либо можно явно указать в web.xml конфигурационный файл

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Второй вариант это **вместо** <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>?????